# PHP only show form if user is connecting from specific IP

Tags: php, html, ip, ip-address

On my site I have the ability for users to send a message to me. It's stored just in a mysql database.

The url is something like: `www.mysite.com/contact?id=4ijr3943jwswER4we` (some random hash on the end as the id)

I have/had the ability that if **I** go to this url and view the message, then an input box shows and it allows **only me** to reply to the message directly from that page. It does this by checking if the IP that the user is connecting from is **my** ip.

I've found that my IP is dynamic and thus whenever my ip gets reassigned, I'm no longer able to see this input form (since I'm now connecting from a different IP).

Is there a way (apart from setting a static IP on my machine) to achieve this same goal? Obviously checking the IP isn't going to be a long term solution, and I've read that you can't grab a users MAC address either.

If it matters, here's the code I've got for checking the IP:

```
function getClientIP() {

    $ipaddress = '';

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    }
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    }
    else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    else {
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    }

    return $ipaddress;
}
```

And it is checked by:

```
if((getClientIP() == "::1" || getClientIP() == "<my ip>") {
    // show an input box and submit button
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about password authentication?

Comment: I have. There's no login on my site, and so having somewhere you could login and it only allowing an admin to login would seem strange, no? If I needed to I could hide a page somewhere where I could login and use that, but since I've had a simple solution thus far I'm trying to keep it that way. If there's nothing as simple I'll probably add something like that though!

Comment: thought about if the user is behind a proxy?

Comment: @Sej most pages have a dedicated url like `/admin` or `/config` to login. This page isn't visible for the normal user and just available if you know the url of it.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the blatant disregard security and the fact that I would fire someone for doing this but you could have a &admin=$value in the url. Something like this.

```
function is_admin() {

    $password = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "password", FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    if ($password == "abc123") {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

so you can replace getClientIP() with is_admin()

```
if(is_admin()) {
    // show an input box and submit button
}
```

and then call it like this.

```
http://www.example.com/contact?id=4ijr3943jwswER4we&admin=abc123
```

again, this is a horribly insecure solution and you should be using a PKI with ssh port forwarding a VPN connection but this works but I'm a sucker for an easy 10 point answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a free dynamic DNS service. Set up a domain, such as "MINE.COM", and use that instead of your IP. When your IP changes, the dynamic DNS service is supposed to adjust, so that MINE.COM is changed to point to the new IP. Your site can check the client for MINE.COM instead of the IP.

Be warned there is a lag time involved. It could be minutes or hours before "MINE.COM" reflects the updated IP. Plus, most "free" services involve advertising which might render your setup unusable.

Bottom line, without a static IP, you're pretty much hosed. A static IP is certainly possible, but usually costs more, as generally only larger concerns like schools, governments or businesses want or need one.

I suggest you investigate using an alternate method, such as a login form, passwords, sessions, cookies, etc. E.g., login as your admin account, establish a cookie on your device, then the next time you visit the site, it can authenticate your device's cookie.